# as_tibble.matrix() failures at tibble 2.0.1

Tags: r, tibble

I have the following `tibble` and I get the warning below. I have tried the `.name_repair` option but it still gives a warning.
Please advise.

```
> as_tibble(diag(3), validate = TRUE)
`as_tibble.matrix()` requires a matrix with column names or a `.name_repair` argument. Using compatibility `.name_repair`.
This warning is displayed once per session.
> packageVersion("tibble")
[1] ‘2.0.1’
```

Comment: The warning seems to be friendly.  Isn't that giving output.  It is having some issues because the matrix didn't have any column names `m1 <- diag(3);
 colnames(m1) <- paste0("V", 1:3); as_tibble(m1, validate = TRUE)`

Comment: For me, if I load the package (same version) `library(tibble);as_tibble(diag(3), validate = TRUE)`, the warning is not there

Comment: The `validate` argument seems to be deprecated. `.name_repair = "unique"` should be your expected behavior I think.